# IE doesn't seem to like bootstrap modal, it shows up without rounded corners, gray background, and ugliest of all it shifts the entire page down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, background, modal-dialog, shift

I am novice in using bootstrap into classic ASP, yes that what I am trying :)
And I am struggling with getting the bootstrap modal look the way it looks and behaves in Chrome or Firefox.
When I launch the modal dialog in IE 11 I see
1. Corners are not rounded
2. Backgound stays the same color
3. Entire page shifts down with all its contents, this I later fixed my moving the modal code from just below the <\body> tag to just above <\body> tag.

Its not even half as cool as it looks in othe browsers (WHY?)

I am new to bootstrap and using all the required libraries for JS and bootsrap. Its a standard modal without any change from my end

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by treating IE differently than other browsers and setting different style for IE and different for the rest.

```
<%if Instr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"), "MSIE") > 0 then%> 
    style="width:1000px;position:relative; vertical-align:top;padding-left: 300px;padding-top:100px" 
<%else%> 
    style="position:absolute; vertical-align:top; width:50%!important; left: 25%!important;top: 10%!important" 
<%end if%> >
```

Effects are not the same but its acceptable solution to our customers.
I know its not the perfect solution buts it is one.

Thanks for viewing this page :)

Answer (score -1):

TRY Adding following code in html `<head>` section

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also add following style :

```
.container
{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
.row
{
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.col-sm-4
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```